# How to scale Dapr Component reading from Azure Event Hub

Tags: azure, docker, azure-aks, azure-eventhub, dapr

We have a Dapr enabled component running on AKS that reads from Azure Event Hub.
We now want to scale this component to ensure parallel processing per partition.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/dapr/components-contrib/issues/759) we could achieve this by setting the partitionID for the component.

I just struggle to understand how this deployment should look like.
Would i deploy the same Dapr component multiple times with differnt appIds and different binding-configurations each specifying an explicit partitionID?
Are there any samples for this setup out there? Or is there a better way to ensure parallel reads from EventHub via Dapr ?